# windowbuilder combobox actionPerformed issue

Tags: java, swing, combobox, actionlistener

I'm working on a simple hospital appointment system. My comboboxes are dependant one to another.
[image: interface].

The issue is when I click  the City combobox and select a city, it enters the county actionListener too. Why?

```
private void initialize() {

City cities = new City();
Hospital hospitals = new Hospital();

frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

JLabel lblCity = new JLabel("City");
lblCity.setBounds(25, 25, 25, 14);
frame.getContentPane().add(lblCity);

JComboBox<String> cityBox = new JComboBox<String>(); // CITY

JComboBox<String> hospitalBox = new JComboBox();
hospitalBox.setBounds(99, 141, 265, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(hospitalBox);

JComboBox<String> comboClinic = new JComboBox<String>(); // CLINIC
comboClinic.setEditable(true);
comboClinic.setBounds(99, 101, 265, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(comboClinic);  // CLINIC

JComboBox<String> countyBox = new JComboBox<String>();  // COUNTY
countyBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
});
countyBox.setEditable(true);

countyBox.setBounds(99, 61, 265, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(countyBox); // COUNTY

cityBox.setEditable(true);  // CITY

cityBox.addItem("Istanbul");
cityBox.addItem("Ankara");
cityBox.addItem("Izmir");

cityBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (cityBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Istanbul")) {
            countyBox.removeAllItems(); hospitalBox.removeAllItems();
            String istanbul[] = cities.getIstanbul();
            countyBox.setSelectedItem("Select county");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < istanbul.length; i++) countyBox.addItem(istanbul[i]);
            comboClinic.setSelectedItem("Select clinic");
        }
        else if(cityBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Ankara")) {
            countyBox.removeAllItems(); hospitalBox.removeAllItems();
            String ankara[] = cities.getAnkara();
            countyBox.setSelectedItem("Select county");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < ankara.length; i++) countyBox.addItem(ankara[i]);
            comboClinic.setSelectedItem("Select clinic");
        }
        else if(cityBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Izmir")) {
            countyBox.removeAllItems(); hospitalBox.removeAllItems();
            String izmir[] = cities.getIzmir();
            countyBox.setSelectedItem("Select county");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < izmir.length; i++) countyBox.addItem(izmir[i]);                 
            comboClinic.setSelectedItem("Select clinic");
        }
            
    }
});
cityBox.setSelectedItem("Select City");

cityBox.setBounds(99, 21, 265, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(cityBox); // CITY
```

as you can see there when i select a city, it arranges the cities counties but it also enters the county actionListener too

Comment: Please show us your code so that we can see what you're doing to answer you.

Comment: @TimHunter hello, i added my code. as you can see there when i select a city, it arranges the cities counties but it also enters the county actionListener too.

Comment: [mcve] required .. and keep the tags focused (don't see anything related to javafx, only swing)

Comment: @kleopatra sorry, can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your event-handling block, you make the following call:

```
countyBox.setSelectedItem("Select county");
```

Per the javadoc on JComboBox

> ActionListeners added to the combo box will be notified with an ActionEvent when this method is called.

Thus, you the `ActionListener` you have added to the `countyBox` is responding.

Comment: thank you so much! you can't know how happy i'm now! it worked when i removed the setSelectedItem lines!